# How to think of these different $K$-points of a scheme and Galois action

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, group-actions, schemes

The eventual goal of this question is to better under the action of a Galois group on a scheme defined over a field $K$. Right now I just want to understand how to think about $K$-points and their Galois conjugates.

The $K$ points, or generally $R$-points ($R$ a ring) of a scheme $X$ are morphisms $\text{spec}\ R \to X$, or equivalently ring morphisms $K[X] \to R$, ($K[X]=\mathcal{O}_X(X))$. Suppose moroever $X$ is finite type and affine, for simplicity. Then the usual story explaining $X(R)$ is that they are the intuitive "$R$-valued points" that satisfy the solutions to equations defining $X$.

Recently when trying to define/understand the Galois action of schemes I realized for $K$-points of a Scheme over $K$, there are more $K$-points than I previously thought: for the simplest example, take $\mathbb{A}^1_K$: writing points as morphisms $K[x] \to K$:

$$c_0+c_1x+\cdots c_mx^m \mapsto c_0+c_1 \alpha + \cdots + c_m \alpha ^m $$
$$c_0+c_1x+\cdots c_mx^m \mapsto c_0+c_1 (\sigma\alpha) + \cdots + c_m(\sigma \alpha) ^m$$

This is what I would think of is the natural meaning of a Galois action on $K$-points. However I also can think of two other maps:

$$c_0+c_1x+\cdots c_mx^m \mapsto \sigma c_0+\sigma c_1 \alpha + \cdots + \sigma c_m \alpha ^m $$

$$c_0+c_1x+\cdots c_mx^m \mapsto \sigma c_0+\sigma c_1 (\sigma \alpha) + \cdots + \sigma c_m (\sigma \alpha ^m) $$

The first pair of maps is what I would naively call the $\sigma$ action on $K$-points. However, I am not sure it is the correct notion. My basic question is, which (pair) of theses maps deserves to be identified with the pair of points $(\alpha, \sigma \alpha)$. The only straightforward relation I see among these maps is that map 4 can be obtained from map $1$ by post-composing with $\sigma$. But they have the same kernels, which I don't know is relevant of not. What is the proper way to think about the relationship between these different maps?

(I am aware that a bunch of these maps can be cut out by working in $\text{Sch}_{/K}$ and requiring the maps to commute with the respective structure morphisms. I hesitate to impose this because I remember reading that the Galois action on schemes over fields does not respect the structure morphism. If I am mistaken, comments correcting my thoughts in this direction would be helpful as well).

Comment: So it seems to me that you want to define $K$-points as maps $\operatorname{Spec}(K) \rightarrow X$ without respecting the structure morphism? That's not how it is defined in e.g. Liu's algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves (See definition 3.30), and as you can see things look pretty weird if you don't have that assumption..

I don't know a reference/answer to your original question though. Intuitively given a scheme $X$ over $k$, it's not clear to me how I can define a Galois action, say of $Gal(L/k)$ on $X$ (and not just $L$-points) in general..

Comment: Well, if in fact the usual definition is to restrict it to maps that respect $K$-alg structure, then I'm happy to accept that. However, I still would like to know which of these maps should correspond to the "coordinate"-wise action on $K$-points. Thanks for the reference, I will look.

Comment: You can check that your second map is the one corresponding to the coordinate-wise action (aside: the third and fourth one are not even $K$-algebra homomorphisms)

Comment: Right, and I supposed the coordinate-wise action is the "correct" one for schemes? Meaning there should be a natural action on schemes that induces this particular action on $K$-points? That is what I assumed, and I tried to imitate the proof of Yoneda to deduce what the action must be but became horribly confused, hence these questions.

Comment: I'm not sure if you should expect to get a natural action on schemes. If you have $Gal(K/k)$ acting on $X$ for some (let's say finite for example) extension $K/k$, then how does this act on $X(\overline{k})$ points for example? I don't think there's a natural way of doing this - but I could be wrong.

Comment: If I had a $\text{Gal}(K/k)$ action on schemes, if anything it should be a morphism $X \to X$, and so would define an action on the $\bar{k}$ points or for that matter $R$ pts for any $K$-alg $R$ by the usual functor of points business, right? Moreover if it induces the coordinate wise action as I hope it does, then on $X(\bar{k})$ it would just be the coordinate wise action extending $\sigma: K \to K$ to an automorphism of $\bar{k}$ in the usual way? I also might be confused. Anyways, thanks for your comments.

Comment: Yes but there are many ways of extending $K\rightarrow K$ to $\bar{k} \rightarrow \bar{k}$!